# How to get past hour results from google custom search api in Python?

Tags: jquery, python

I want to know how to tweak `dateRestrict` variable to find articles posted in last half an hour. However, I am unable to do so - any help would be appreciated.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pprint

my_api_key = "Google API key"
my_cse_id = "Custom Search Engine ID"

def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
   service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()
    return res['items']

results = google_search(
    'stackoverflow site:en.wikipedia.org', my_api_key, my_cse_id,dateRestrict=d1, num=10)
for result in results:
pprint.pprint(result)
```